# How to login to microsoft's @live.com ID on Nokia Lumia 820?

Tags: 8.1, windows-live

I'm using Lumia 820 and want to shift the maps storage to SD card. For this I need to download *Lumia Storage Check Beta*. When I try to install it, I'm asked for my Microsoft Account password.

The problem is that in Username, it is showing `my_name@live.com` whereas my Microsoft Account username is `my_name@gmail.com`. The username can't be edited and my password isn't being accepted. How can I change the username of the Microsoft Account on my phone?

Comment: Any accounts in the phone are listed in Settings > Email+Account

Answer (score 3):

Your @live account is being shown as it's the first Microsoft Account you have added to your phone. Changing the primary account can only be done after a hard reset. For this, navigate to Settings -> about and hit the "reset your phone" button and confirm.